# Executing a url without opening it on the browser in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a local page that pulls data from a database and sends out a message. So I'm trying to have this page executed using javascript on "`success`" of another function. The problem is everything I've tried doesn't seem to execute that page, while the only success I've had on executing that page is using a window pop up, which is not desired.

This is the pop up code (undesired):

```
function sendMsg(){
    var wnd = window.open("http://localhost/url");
    if(wnd){
            setTimeout(function () { wnd.close();}, 4000);
    }
}
sendMsg();
```

And these are the codes I've tried but didn't execute the url:

```
$.get("http://localhost/url")
```

And this one which is from another answer here on SO.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText; returned value
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/url",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

How can I have this URL executed without opening it on the browser in any way?
Just to be clear, I know the other two codes didn't work because I would have received a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe jQuery's load() method may be useful for this. For example, have a div in your HTML and just set it to hidden in the CSS.

[jQuery load() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='myHiddenPage'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myHiddenPage { 
    display: none;
}
```

**jQUERY:**

```
$(funtion() {
    $('#myHiddenPage').load('www.myurl.com');
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use this trick to call url that downloads excel file?
I tried, but the excel content is getting rendered in this div, instead of downloading the file.

Answer (score 3):

if you really need a return data/page from get

you should do something like this.

```
$.get( "url", function( data ) {
  console.log(data); // return data/page
  alert( "Done load." );
});
```

@ use ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "GET",
  success   : function( data ){
    console.log(data); // return data/page
    alert("Done LOad");
  }
});
```

anything else can refer : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I tried the above code too, it would output in the console the code from the file I was calling. I only wanted it executed. But I've gotten a work around from iPzard's answer